# robot climbing ladder with different probability to climb up at each bar

Tags: probability

there is a ladder with 4 bars, a ground bar marked as bar 0. no bars beneath bar 0. no bar above bar 4. A robot starts climbing it up from bar 0. He will climb up or down the bars depending on the probability, at each bar, there is different probability to climb up as follows:

to climb up successfully:

from bar 0 to bar 1 : 1/3

bar 1 to bar 2: 1/4

bar 2 to bar 3: 1/5

bar 3 to bar 4: 1/6

if he fails, he will only drop down 1 bar. ex: from bar 3 to bar 2.

**Question:
what is the chance for robot climbing up to the 4th bar within N times?**

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: sorry about that, just edited.

Comment: You haven't specified what happens when the robot fails to climb from bar $0$ to bar $1$. Does it stay at bar $0$ then?

Comment: yes, it does, it will just stay at bar 0

Comment: You should really grab an elementary text on finite Markov chains, this kind of question is quite standard... [Norris](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/) comes to mind.

Comment: okay! this still helps, I'll start look for that, much appreciated!